# what is the best way to add multiple Start URLs in Scrapy Crawlspider with different allowed domains?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

currently, I'm using the below code to add multiple start URLs (50K).

```
start_urls=[]
allowed_domains=[]    
df=pd.read_excel("xyz.xlsx")    
for url in df['URL']:    
    start_urls.append(parent_url)    
    allowed_domains.append(tldextract.extract(parent_url).registered_domain)
```

But, I think this will not keep the different allowed domains for each website. and I also want to pass some meta information with each link.

Comment: if you want  different allowed domains then you have to run in separted spiders.

Comment: how to create and manage 50K spiders?

Comment: you can start crawler/spider with arguments using `-a NAME=VALUE` - so you can create one spider and run it with different arguments.

Comment: other idea: if you use `Request()` then you could send `meta={}` to send `domain` to function which parses response and it could use `domain` to filter urls for next `Request` (which would have to also send `domain`) - but it would need only starndard `Request` to scrape urls.

Comment: Yes, I have used meta parameter in regular spider with def start_requests() function calling other functions. but it didn't work with multiple start URLs with CrawlSpider.

Comment: you may get path to source code `scapy.__file__` and check how it works in `CrawlSpider`. Or you can even get source code of `CrawlSpider` and create own spider.